# Task cancel Method or Event

Tags: java, networking, javafx, concurrency

I'm trying to create an networking javafx application and running the serverloop in a task. Because the ServerSocket accept method is blocking and I'm not able to test if the task was canceled (with isCancelled()).

**My Current Implementation:**

```
class ServerTask extends Task<Void> {
    ExecutorService executorService;
    final int PORT = 12345;

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            while (true)
            {
                executorService.execute(
                        new Client(serverSocket.accept()));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to override or catch an event when chancel is called on a task or is my way to implement the serverloop in javafx applications wrong? If so, how should it be done?

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you're doing? A call to `ServerSocket.accept()` can be (effectively) interrupted by closing the socket, if that helps.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I would like to call that through something like a deconstructor

Comment: There is no deconstructor in Java. Not quite sure what you mean there.

Comment: I thougt about overriding the cancel method because it is only calling cancel(true), but I'm a newbie in JavaFX and dont want to corrupt something.

Comment: JavaFX is fairly good (at least, better than Swing) at [making methods final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#cancel--) if they should not be overridden. I think the correct approach here is to override [`cancelled()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#cancelled--), which is specifically (and explicitly) designed for overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Task` will transition to the `CANCELLED` state as soon as `cancel()` is invoked, even if the `call()` method is still blocked running an uninterruptible method.

A `ServerSocket` can effectively be "interrupted" by closing the socket, which will cause any `accept()` method that is currently blocked to terminate with an `IOException`.

So you can do something like this:

```
class ServerTask extends Task<Void> {
    ExecutorService executorService;
    final int PORT = 12345;

    private ServerSocket serverSocket ;

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

        try (serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            while (true)
            {
                executorService.execute(
                        new Client(serverSocket.accept()));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                System.out.println("Cancelled");
            } else {
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void cancelled() {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a very quick complete example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NonIterruptableTaskCancellation extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(2048);

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                while (! isCancelled()) {
                    try {
                        Socket s = socket.accept();
                        System.out.println("Connected to "+s);
                        s.close();
                    } catch (IOException exc) {
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            System.out.println("Cancelled");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Unexpected IO Exception");
                            throw exc ;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null ;
            }

            @Override
            protected void cancelled() {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(task);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();

        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(task.stateProperty().asString());

        Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.disableProperty().bind(task.runningProperty().not());
        cancel.setOnAction(e -> task.cancel());

        VBox root = new VBox(5, label, cancel);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```